# How to change date in this calendar using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape through this website using Python and Selenium: https://markets.ft.com/data/etfs/tearsheet/historical?s=O9P:SES:USD.

I need to change years on the left calendar, in order to see the 2018 prices. 
Even though I manage to change year and select 2018 in the dropdown menu, I can't click on the day (for example, 1 Jan 2018). It is weird since I have no problem with clicking on a day in 2019.

I really don't know why. Here's the code which does not work.

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.o-grid-container.mod-container > div:nth-child(2) > section.mod-main-content > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.mod-ui-filter-overlay.clearfix.mod-filter-ui-historical-prices-overlay > div.mod-ui-overlay.mod-ui-filter-overlay__form > div > form > fieldset > span > div.mod-ui-date-picker.mod-filter-ui-historical-prices-overlay__date--from > div.mod-ui-date-picker__input-container > i").click()
    select_element_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='mod-ui-date-picker mod-filter-ui-historical-prices-overlay__date--from']//select[option[@value = '%d']]" %lastyear)
    select_from = Select(select_element_from)
    select_from.select_by_visible_text(lastyearstr)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='mod-ui-date-picker mod-filter-ui-historical-prices-overlay__date--from']//*[@aria-label='1 Jan, %d']" %(y-1)).click()
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your code: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='mod-ui-date-picker mod-filter-ui-historical-prices-overlay__date--from']//*[@aria-label='1 Jan, %d']" %(y-1)).click()` the element is not displayed. Since the element is not visible on the browser, it cannot be clicked.

I've adopted a step-by-step approach simulating what a user would do as he clicks through the webpage. Here is the code which works:

```
# Find the element that expands the date picker
filter_arg = '//span[@class="o-labels" and @aria-hidden="false"]'
filter_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath(filter_arg)
filter_icon.click()

# Find the calendar icon
cal_arg = '//i[@class="mod-icon mod-icon--calendar"]'
cal_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath(cal_arg)
cal_icon.click()

# Find the dropdown selector that selects the year
year_arg = '//select[@class="picker__select--year"]'
year_selector = driver.find_element_by_xpath(year_arg)
year_selector.click()

# Find '2018'
last_year = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[@value="2018"]')
last_year.click()

# Find all the days that are available, and click on the one with the relevant `.text` attribute
which_day = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="picker__day picker__day--infocus"]')
which_day[0].text
'1'

# If i want to click on the 4th day of the month...
which_day[3].click()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I tried it once and worked perfectly, but for no reason the second time (and all the other times) I tried to run that, it stopped working. Do you have any suggestion? I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you able to paste the error here? Usually it is due to stale element, no such element, WebDriverException, etc. The error message will be very important in diagnosing what happened here. :)

Comment: There are not errors, it does not click on the date but selects the 2018 year in the dropdown menu. I really don't understand what happens. Could you try to run it in Python?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, just make sure you:
1. Do not click on the filter icon again, as it would close the date picker.
2. Click on a different date. 
Do note that if you have clicked on 4-Jan-2018, the "class" attribute would be modified to `class="picker__day picker__day--infocus picker__day--selected picker__day--highlighted"`, hence it would not be found by `which_day = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="picker__day picker__day--infocus"]')`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with python but I'm using your code and it does not work, does not matter if I'm clicking on a different date. I have no idea why, I also put some sleep().